# Cheap thin client setup with Puppy linux?

Tags: usb-drive, live-usb

Looking through the [Puppylinux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) pages today, I wondered if it could be used to setup a low-cost thin client, that booted from a USB flashdrive or something. Considering these points:

- Low speed CPU such as P4/Dualcore is fine (cheaper)
- No HDD needed (saves $100)
- No SATA / IDE ports on motherboard needed (cheaper)

So does this allow for a cheap thin client build? Are there any motherboards that cost like $100 for a basic linux experience? Do you get low-cost motherboards or mini-computers that could work well as thin clients with a tiny OS like puppylinux?

Comment: Some of the older laptops are good candidates for this. Pentium-Mobile business-class laptops like Thinkpads. For newer components the bottom rung would be an Atom-based Nettop for about $200. If you aren't stuck on x86, then the Raspberry Pi would be a good candidate too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago I bought HP Compaq t5000 Thin Client ([t5710 model](http://www.google.pl/search?q=t5710&tbm=isch) (it was really cheap (about $100) on some auction portal)) and it is great for my needs. I'm using it as:

- VPN server
- ssh server for accessing my home network
- wake on lan for other devices
- from time to time as webserver
- battery charger for my mobile.. ;)

CPU:

```
pbm@lantea:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineTMx86
cpu family  : 5
model       : 4
model name  : Transmeta(tm) Crusoe(tm) Processor TM5700
stepping    : 3
cpu MHz     : 798.106
cache size  : 256 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 1
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr cx8 sep cmov mmx longrun lrti constant_tsc up
bogomips    : 1596.21
clflush size    : 32
cache_alignment : 32
address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

Memory:

```
pbm@lantea:~$ free -m
             total         used         free       shared      buffers
Mem:           485           23          462            0            3
-/+ buffers:                 19          466
Swap:            0            0            0
```

Disk - there is Disk-on-module connected through 44 pin (laptop) ATA connector. It can be replaced by 2.5" HDD or 3.5 HDD using adapter.

```
pbm@lantea:~$ df -h /
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root               473.2M    162.3M    286.5M  36% /
```

You can also use 4 USB ports to connect HDD or some USB storage. It can also boot OS from USB (internal disk and PXE is also supported).

Currently I have on it [Slitaz](http://www.slitaz.org/) distribution (ISO with X server and some WM - 30 MB!, minimal ISO - 8 MB), and there is a lot of free space on internal disk. List of installed packages you can find [here](http://wklej.org/id/714834/).

Originally it was shipped with Windows XP Embedded (there is image to download in HP KB) with RDP and Citrix clients.

Answer (score -1):

I put Puppy on a Dell Optiplex 170 I purchased for $60.00. I put Puppy directly on the 4gb drive. Works great for just browsing the net.